# Append information to TableLayout in Thread

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how to access the View from a thread in my MainActivity class.  I need to be able to append information to the table every 5 seconds as it is gathered. How would I go about doing this when the function is in a `Thread()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a one Hanlder as field and initialize it in onCreate of your activity. 
And then with that Hanlder access UI Thread. i.e Access Views

Or Simply  use

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               //code needs to be ran in UI thread)

            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm very new to Java, do you have an example you could link to?

Comment: @MasterGberry Check this http://crodrigues.com/updating-the-ui-from-a-background-thread-on-android/